Unexpected NDMI Values: Low NDMI for Water, High NDMI for Forests
I’m working on a project analyzing NDMI values derived from Sentinel-2 L2A satellite imagery, and I’ve encountered some unexpected results. Specifically:

My NDMI values for water bodies are consistently low (-0.1 to 0.1).
My NDMI values for forests are high (around 0.3), which aligns with
what I’d expect for moist vegetation.

Based on my understanding, water bodies typically have high NDMI values due to their high moisture content, while drier land areas should exhibit lower values. Here’s some context for my work:
I’m using the formula: NDMI = (NIR - SWIR) / (NIR + SWIR).
The Near-Infrared (Band 08 10m) and Shortwave Infrared (Band 11 20m) bands I’m using are from Sentinel-2 L2A data.
Preprocessing steps include atmospheric correction and cloud masking.
Given that water bodies are showing low NDMI values, I suspect there may be an issue with data processing, band selection, or atmospheric effects impacting my results.
Has anyone encountered similar issues or can offer insights on potential causes and troubleshooting steps? Any suggestions or tips?
Edit:
I have added a picture, the color scheme is brown (-1) to green (1).


What is the overall goal? Have you checked the values against a resource such as this: https://eos.com/make-an-analysis/ndmi/

The link @GeoMonkey gives , gives a nice description of NDMI and suggests if you want to extract water bodies use the NDWI instead.
